# The property System.Boolean IsReadOnly=False

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2014

Can anyone help me on below issue.

```
###############################
# retrieve Rule Definitions
###############################
AGTrace ""
AGTrace "====================================="
AGTrace "Retrieving AGTL Rule Definitions"
AGTrace "====================================="
#remove read-only flag on local rule definitions
try {
    Get-ChildItem "$LocalPath\ruledefinitions" | Set-ItemProperty -name IsReadOnly -value $false
} catch {
    Write-host "Unable to clear read-only flag"
    Write-host $error[0].exception.message
}
Copy-Files -SourceFolder "$AGSource\AGTL\RuleDefinitions" -DestFolder "$LocalPath\ruledefinitions" 

AGTrace ""
AGTrace "====================================="
AGTrace "Retrieving $AGID Rule Definitions"
AGTrace "====================================="
if (test-path "$AGSource\$AGID\RuleDefinitions") {
    AGTrace "Rule Definitions exist for $AGID"
    Copy-Files -SourceFolder "$AGSource\$AGID\RuleDefinitions" -DestFolder "$LocalPath\ruledefinitions"
} else {
    AGTrace "No Rule Definitions exist for $AGID"
}
```

> Message Executed as user: abc\ankq_adc_AGd_extr. Set-ItemProperty :
>   The property System.Boolean IsReadOnly=False does not exist or was not
>   found.  At
>   E:\AGD4.0.1\Full\DW-Extractor\AGDiagnostics_R4.0.1_CoreInstall\AG4STG_4.0.0\execute_load_JP.ps1:145
>   char:47  + Get-ChildItem "$LocalPath\SupplementalAGta" |
>   Set-ItemProperty -name IsReadOnly  ...  +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          :
>   ReadError: (System.Boolean IsReadOnly=False:PSNoteProperty)
>   [Set-ItemProperty], IOExcept      ion      + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   SetPropertyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand.
>   Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to use set-itemproperty ,the below code should be fine for changing property to readonly:

```
 Get-ChildItem "D:\testfolder" | %{$_.isreadonly = $true}
```

you can do the same with set-itemproperty:

```
 Get-ChildItem "D:\testfolder" | Get-ItemProperty | Set-ItemProperty -name IsReadOnly -value $false
```

Comment: I will check now @Abhijith.Thanks for the response

Comment: @SQLBoy if the destination folder contains folders inside then you might have to add a check for applying this only on files inside the folder as this only applies for files

Comment: Sure @Abhijith,Thanks a lot

Comment: ,can you please tell me if this error is version dependent.Why this error occurs ?